# systemd: default value for environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, systemd, init-script, init.d, openrc

I would like to migrate some OpenRC init script to systemd but I think that it is general problem of environment variables handling in systemd.

**Original OpenRC files**

There is a file e.g. `/etc/conf.d/fooservice` with contents

```
# value of FOO variable
# you can override default value by uncomenting this line
# FOO=value1

# value of BAR variable
BAR=value2
```

In original startup script `/etc/init.d/fooservice`, there was

```
FOO=${FOO:-default_foo_value}
BAR=${BAR:-default_bar_value}
```

So the result was `$FOO==default_foo_value` and `$BAR==value2`

**Migrated systemd files**

Now I have systemd service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/fooservice.service`, that contains

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/fooservice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fooservice $FOO $BAR
```

But there is a problem that `$FOO` is not initialized to `default_foo_value`

Is there a way to tell systemd to use default value if there is no value in environment file? Is there a way to use intermediate environment file with default values or multiple chained Environment files?

**SOLUTION:**

This is not good way. `/etc/conf.d/fooservice` file can be incompatible because it is "shell script" and systemd expects "environment file". In basic value assignment, it seems similar, but it is not the same thing.

Prefered solution for this by Gentoo is to put everything into service file and configuration file of the service and not to use additional `conf.d` file.

**WORKING BUT NOT PREFERED SOLUTION:**

Use this only as fast hack to run OpenRC service as systemd one.

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/fooservice.service` now contains

```
[Service]
Environment="FOO=default_foo_value"
Environment="BAR=default_bar_value"
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/fooservice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fooservice $FOO $BAR
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

systemd is not a shell, so it does not support shell-specific substitutions in environment files. Their format is simply `KEY=VALUE`, with possible empty lines and comments in between.

To quote [systemd.exec(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=):

> Settings from these files override settings made with Environment=. If the same variable is set twice from these files, the files will be read in the order they are specified and the later setting will override the earlier setting.

So, you can accomplish your task by either:

- using multiple `EnvironmentFile=` directives (they override each other in the order of specification)
- using `Environment=` in the service file to specify default values (any `EnvironmentFile=` will override it)

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed the part about "... If the same variable is set twice..." so I didn't beleave that it is order dependent.